# Transpose table

Tags: python, unix, awk, sed

I want to transpose a file like below, where the 2nd column and onward each column header (B4, B3, E0) can take two values. I want all the values for `B4 B3 ...` to be in one row.  Which means `B4 B3 E0` will be separate rows.

How can it be done with e.g. awk sed or python. I can do simple transpose in python but I don't understand how to solve this particular problem.

Input : 2nd and 3rd column have the same column name i.e B4, similarly 4th and 5th column have same column name i.e B3 and so on.When we transpose both the values corresponding to B4 should transpose together as a unit like `12 13 13 14 13 13 12 13 13 13 12 13`.  It should be on one line.  The input file consists of over 20 columns and 2000 rows.

Input:

```
ID  B4    B3    
 1  12  13  19  21  
 2  13  14  19  21  
 3  13  13  19  21  
 4  12  13  19  19  
 5  13  13  18  19  
 6  12  13  19  21
```

Desired Output:

```
ID 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
B4 12  13 13  14 13  13 12  13 13  13 12  13
B3 19  21 19  21 19  21 19  19 18  19 19  21
```

This is what i have tried:

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(' '.join(c) for c in zip(*(l.split() for l in sys.stdin.readlines() if l.strip()))))" < input file>output file
```

Also tried an `awk` code but with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) col[i]=$i }
     NR>1{ 
         col[1]=sprintf("%s %s %s",col[1],$1,$1); j=1; 
         for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) {
             j++; col[j]=sprintf("%s %s %s",col[j],$i,$(i+1)) 
         }
     }
     END { len=length(col); for (i=1; i<=len; i++) print col[i] }' input
```

The output:

```
ID 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
B4 12 13 13 14 13 13 12 13 13 13 12 13
B3 19 21 19 21 19 21 19 19 18 19 19 21
```

---

- `NR==1{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) col[i]=$i }` - accumulating column names on the 1st line
- `col[1]=sprintf("%s %s %s",col[1],$1,$1)` - concatenating values for the 1st `ID` column
- `j++; col[j]=sprintf("%s %s %s",col[j],$i,$(i+1))` - concatenating values for each next column (two values per each column)

Answer (score 1):

This python code solves your issue

```
import sys

header = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()
transposed = [[item] for item in header]

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    items = line.strip().split()
    transposed[0].append(items[0])
    for i in range(1, len(transposed)):
        transposed[i].extend(items[2*i - 1: 2*i + 1])

for line in transposed:
    print(" ".join(line))
```

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks!

Comment: This answer does not duplicate column 1 elements as specified by the OP

Comment: You are right, yet it is easily fixed by adding a duplicate line of `transposed[0].append(items[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it with coreutils and datamash, assuming the input data is tab-separated:

```sh
# Name of the input file
infile=input
(
  # Grab header
  head -n1 $infile

  # Combine columns without the header, 1. duplicate every line, 
  # 2. and 3. zip columns together
  paste <(tail -n+2 $infile | cut -f 1   | sed 'h; G')     \
        <(tail -n+2 $infile | cut -f 2,3 | sed 's/\t/\n/') \
        <(tail -n+2 $infile | cut -f 4,5 | sed 's/\t/\n/')
) | datamash transpose
```

Output:

```
ID  1   1   2   2   3   3   4   4   5   5   6   6
B4  12  13  13  14  13  13  12  13  13  13  12  13
B3  19  21  19  21  19  21  19  19  18  19  19  21
```

If the input is not tab-separated, you can make it so with `sed`:

```
sed 's/^ *\| *$//g; s/ \+/\t/g' infile > outfile
```